SoundCoud App Registration is not possible [2024]
As I can understand from this output, at the moment there is no new registrations possible to enable SouncCloud app/widget. I was unable to reach contact information of support/development team at SoundCloud.
Is there a way to fetch songs and create your playlists?
When I want to register for an application, here: https://soundcloud.com/you/apps
I receive the output that is visible on the image:
Message
